# Issue with creating a simple food list app by redux in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a simple food list app, I want the user write the name of food in textinput ( in input screen) and click on submit button then those name that have been written get printed in another screen ( named foodlist screen), All states are going to work via redux.

**I have two problems:**

**1: Submit button doesn't work, it means when user start to typing in text input all letters get printed, I want it happen when user click on submit button**

**2:If user type a five letter word, Redux print five items in foodlist screen ( like has shown in folowing pic)**

How can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

**This the reducer code:**

```
import {
    ADDFOOD,
    REMOVEFOOD,
    CLEANTEXT




} from '../actions/types';

initialState = {

    foodList: []

}




export const foodReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADDFOOD:
            return {
                ...state,
                foodList: state.foodList.concat({
                    name: action.payload,
                    index: Math.random()
                })
            }
            break;
        case REMOVEFOOD:
            return {
                ...state,
                foodList: state.foodList.filter((item) =>
                    item.index !== action.payload

                )
            }
            break;

        case CLEANTEXT:
            return {
                ...state,
                foodList: ''
            }
            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }



}
```

**This is the text input code:**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addFood, cleanText } from '../actions';



const Login = (props) => {

  const { navigation } = props;
  const foodList = useSelector(state => state.foodR.foodList);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (


    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20 }}>Login Form</Text>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Food name'
        onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(addFood(value))}
        value={foodList}





      />

      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        style={styles.button}


      >

        <Text style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>Submit</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {

          navigation.navigate('FoodList');

        }}

      >

        <Text style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>Go to Food list</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity>








    </View>






  )

}
```

**And this is the foodlist code:**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFood } from '../actions';






const FoodList = () => {



    const foodList = useSelector(state => state.foodR.foodList);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();





    return (

        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={foodList}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.button}
                            activeOpacity={0.7}
                            onPress={(index) => dispatch(removeFood(item.index))}
                        >


                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 10 }} >{item.name}</Text>


                            <Icon type='FontAwesome5' name='trash' style={{ fontSize: 25, marginRight: 10 }} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    )} />

            </View>
        </View>

    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the action every time the text changes

`onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(addFood(value))}`

What you want to do is store the value not in redux but in local state using the hook useState()

Then when submit is pressed add a line which takes the latest state stored locally and dispatches this to redux:

```
onPress={() => {
   // get the local state and call dispatch(removeFood(item.index))
   navigation.navigate('FoodList');
}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, It worked and my issue was completely solved, But i wonder is there any way that i don't use local state (useState hook) ? is it possible i get text input value via redux without any useState?  I would prefer to use global states than local states

Comment: Yep so absoltely you can get rid of local state entirely and store everything in redux.  So every time the text changes redux store gets updated and the value passed back in via the props.  This is a pure aproach and not bad as it means your components are purely a function of the props.  The only downside is there could be a slight performance hit as text change does happen a lot.  Not a big issue though.

Comment: So maybe a new action like somthing like:
dispatch(setFoodText(value))
And pickup from 
state.currentFood 
Pass that through the props
state.props.currentFood